# Jenkins pipeline to pull the image from ACR and do image scan using kubernetes pods as agent

Tags: jenkins, cicd, kaniko, acr, trivy

I have created a pipeline:

```java
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      yaml '''
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Pod
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: trivy
            image: aquasec/trivy:latest
            command:
            - cat
            tty: true
            volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
                name: docker-sock
          - name: kaniko
            image: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            command:
            - sleep
            args: 
            - 9999999
            volumeMounts:
            - name: kaniko-secret
              mountPath: /kaniko/.docker
          restartPolicy: Never
          volumes:
          - name: kaniko-secret
            secret: 
              secretName: acr-secret
              items:
                - key: .dockerconfigjson
                  path: config.json
          - name: docker-sock
            hostPath:
               path: /var/run/docker.sock
      '''
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Checkout') {
      steps {
        // Checkout code from a Git repository and specific branch
        git branch: 'main', 
          credentialsId: 'jenkinscred1',
          url: 'https://github.com/premajanakkumar/dockerbuild-bushto-acr.git'
      }
    }
    stage('Build with Kaniko') {
      steps {
        container('kaniko') {
          script {
            sh '''
              /kaniko/executor --dockerfile `pwd`/Dockerfile \
                --context `pwd` \
                --destination ****.azurecr.io/exampledevsecopspetstore:300
            '''
          }
        }
      } 
    }
    stage('image scan with trivy') {
      steps {
        container('trivy') {
          script {
            sh '''
              trivy image --format json \
                -o trivy_report.json \
                 exampledevsecopspetstore.azurecr.io/exampledevsecopspetstore:300
            '''
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This pipeline automates the process of checking out source code from a Git repository, building a Docker image using Kaniko in a Kubernetes environment, and scanning the resulting image for vulnerabilities using Trivy.

I am getting unauthorized error from azure container service, how to authorize from trivy container to ACR?